# Azure ML job started to fail with DataAccessError : Invalid secret token header

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, datastore

I have been running the very same Azure ML job before Christmas, but yesterday it started to throw a DataAccessError while trying to mount a uri_folder from a Datastore. I have not changed any setting, storage account keys are the same, and in fact no authentication is set up for the datastore at Azure ML. I have hidden relevant info from the log but did not introduce changes between last month's job and yesterday's.

I am using Azure CLI 2.39.0 to launch the job with the very same YAML template.

The only change I noticed between jobs is the azureml_dataprep version, it was 4.8.1 before and now it is 4.8.3. Let me share a snippet of the data_capability.log at AzureML Job logs:

INFO 2023-01-05 11:12:28,625 cr_utilities.py:434 [30] - Installed python package versions. {'azureml_core': '1.45.0.post3', **'azureml_dataprep': '4.8.3'**, 'azureml_dataprep_rslex': '2.15.1',...}

And for the rest of the log just remarked in bold characters the error description:

**"exception":"DataAccessError(Unknown("an unexpected error occurred while resolving AccessToken ClientAuthenticationError: Unexpected content type \"text/plain; charset=utf-8\"\nContent: Invalid secret token header: XXXX", None))",**

```
**ERROR 2023-01-04 11:34:14,976 cr_utilities.py:157 [28] - ##[error] Data capability failure**
{
   "exception":"PyFuseError",
   "subscription_id":"XXXX",
   "resource_group":"XXXX",
   "workspace_name":"XXXX",
   "workspace_location":"XXXX",
   "experiment_name":"azureml",
   "node_rank":"None",
   "node_id":"tvmps_b0220a4fc0d982fccb02adbe37176fd32d427a576e356b4f56cc806efd97ab8b_d",
   "root_run_id":"XXXX",
   "run_id":"XXXX",
   "correlation_id":"XXXX",
   "source":"common_runtime.data-capability",
   "session_id":"8e522bb0-c461-442b-8342-c2a0609bf30a",
   "version":"0.0.1.20221213.1",
   "commit":"XXXX",
   "branch":"origin/XXXX",
   "os":"linux",
   "TraceId":"538b20ae3ae639547c41eb120ac98b60",
   "SpanId":"3bed598aa514feb7",
   "TraceFlags":"01",
   "traceId":"538b20ae3ae639547c41eb120ac98b60",
   "spanId":"3bed598aa514feb7",
   "custom_dimensions":{
      "exception":"PyFuseError",
      "subscription_id":"XXXX",
      "resource_group":"XXXX",
      "workspace_name":"XXXX",
      "workspace_location":"XXXX",
      "experiment_name":"azureml",
      "node_rank":"None",
      "node_id":"tvmps_b0220a4fc0d982fccb02adbe37176fd32d427a576e356b4f56cc806efd97ab8b_d",
      "root_run_id":"XXXX",
      "run_id":"XXXX",
      "correlation_id":"XXXX",
      "source":"common_runtime.data-capability",
      "session_id":"8e522bb0-c461-442b-8342-c2a0609bf30a",
      "version":"0.0.1.20221213.1",
      "commit":"XXXX",
      "branch":"origin/XXXX",
      "os":"linux",
      "TraceId":"538b20ae3ae639547c41eb120ac98b60",
      "SpanId":"3bed598aa514feb7",
      "TraceFlags":"01",
      "traceId":"538b20ae3ae639547c41eb120ac98b60",
      "spanId":"3bed598aa514feb7"
   }
}



**ERROR 2023-01-04 11:34:14,977 capability_session.py:102 [28] - ##[error] [CapabilitySession][start] Failed to start data session.** 

{
   "session_name":"XXXX",
   **"exception":"DataAccessError(Unknown(\"an unexpected error occurred while resolving AccessToken ClientAuthenticationError: Unexpected content type \\\"text/plain; charset=utf-8\\\"\\nContent: Invalid secret token header: XXXX\", None))",**
   "subscription_id":"XXXX",
   "resource_group":"XXXX",
   "workspace_name":"XXXX",
   "workspace_location":"XXXX",
   "experiment_name":"azureml",
   "node_rank":"None",
   "node_id":"tvmps_b0220a4fc0d982fccb02adbe37176fd32d427a576e356b4f56cc806efd97ab8b_d",
   "root_run_id":"XXXX",
   "run_id":"XXXX",
   "correlation_id":"XXXX",
   "source":"common_runtime.data-capability",
   "session_id":"8e522bb0-c461-442b-8342-c2a0609bf30a",
   "version":"0.0.1.20221213.1",
   "commit":"XXXX",
   "branch":"origin/XXXX",
   "os":"linux",
   "TraceId":"538b20ae3ae639547c41eb120ac98b60",
   "SpanId":"3bed598aa514feb7",
   "TraceFlags":"01",
   "traceId":"538b20ae3ae639547c41eb120ac98b60",
   "spanId":"3bed598aa514feb7",
   "custom_dimensions":{
      "session_name":"XXXX",
      **"exception":"DataAccessError(Unknown(\"an unexpected error occurred while resolving AccessToken ClientAuthenticationError: Unexpected content type \\\"text/plain; charset=utf-8\\\"\\nContent: Invalid secret token header: XXXX\", None))"**,
      "subscription_id":"XXXX",
      "resource_group":"XXXX",
      "workspace_name":"XXXX",
      "workspace_location":"XXXX",
      "experiment_name":"azureml",
      "node_rank":"None",
      "node_id":"tvmps_b0220a4fc0d982fccb02adbe37176fd32d427a576e356b4f56cc806efd97ab8b_d",
      "root_run_id":"XXXX",
      "run_id":"XXXX",
      "correlation_id":"XXXX",
      "source":"common_runtime.data-capability",
      "session_id":"8e522bb0-c461-442b-8342-c2a0609bf30a",
      "version":"0.0.1.20221213.1",
      "commit":"XXXX",
      "branch":"origin/XXXX",
      "os":"linux",
      "TraceId":"538b20ae3ae639547c41eb120ac98b60",
      "SpanId":"3bed598aa514feb7",
      "TraceFlags":"01",
      "traceId":"538b20ae3ae639547c41eb120ac98b60",
      "spanId":"3bed598aa514feb7"
   }
}
```

Is there anything that has changed in this month, or to be taken into account due to year change? I checked also that

- the storage account keys have not been regenerated.
- Also did a az ml workspace sync-keys to refresh keys just in case.
- I am able to explore the datastore from which I am trying to mount data from the job at the Azure ML portal.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: OK, it seems that something had corrupted two compute instances which I had assigned to my user and with a system assigned identity. 

Creating a new compute instance with the same settings as the ones I was using previously solved the problem. 

Still don't know what it was causing it, however...

Answer (score 0):

OK, it seems that something had corrupted two compute instances which  had assigned to user and with a system assigned identity. Creating a new compute instance with the same settings as the ones that was using previously solved the problem.